# Adding a Record with same Name but with different other fields with OData in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js, odata

I am working on an application where I am adding a record with fields like product, term, location, bid, offer etc into database table using text boxes in a table row. I am using OData and knockout Js to perform insertion and updating. I have the following code which pushes data into table using OData.

**1. Knockout Js**

```
self.add = function (canadiancrude) {
  var payload = {
      Term: "Term", Product: "Product" , Location: "Location", Pipeline: "Pipeline",
      BidCP: "Bid CP", BidVolume: "Bid Volume", Index: "Index", Bid: "0.0", Offer: "0.0",
      OfferVolume:"Offer Volume", OfferCP:"Offer CP"
  };
$.ajax({
    url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes',
  type: 'POST',
  //  data: ko.toJSON(payload),
  data: JSON.stringify(payload),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json'
});}
```

**> 2. Insertion with Odata**

```
 protected override CanadianCrude CreateEntity(CanadianCrude entity) {
  var newCanadianCrude = db.CanadianCrudes.Add(entity);
  db.SaveChanges();    return newCanadianCrude;}
```

> Now I want to add another record but with the same product and different remaining fields under the parent record as an hierarchy in the UI when I click on add (the plus sign image in the picture) rather than adding an entire row at the bottom as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to the question myself

```
self.copy = function (canadiancrude) {
        var payload = {
            Id: canadiancrude.Id, Term: "", Product: canadiancrude.Product, Location: "", Pipeline: "",
            BidCP: "", BidVolume: "", Index: "", Bid: "0.0", Offer: "0.0",
            OfferVolume: "", OfferCP: ""
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes',
            type: 'POST',
            // data: ko.toJSON(payload),
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function to do that -

```
function copyWhatever(sender) {
    var whatever = new whateverObject(sender.name);
    myObservableArray.push(whatever); 
}

function whateverObject(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.OtherProperties = ko.observable();
}
```